# NullPointerException inside AbsListView

Tags: android, listview

I have an amazing exception in ListView outside of my appication. I've read that it can be caused by mine adapter, that returns null. But my adapter checks for it:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    SmsHolder v;
    if(view == null) {
        if(MainActivity.DEBUG) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_list_item_debug, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_list_item, parent, false);
        }
    }

    v = (SmsHolder) view.getTag(R.id.screenHolder);

    SMS sms = getSMS(position);

    v.date.setText(ZenDate.format(ZenDate.FORMAT_RUS_DM, sms.time_stamp * 1000));
    v.sender.setText(sms.sender + " ");
    v.text.setText(sms.text + " ");
    v.selector.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    v.selector.setChecked(checked.contains(sms._id));
    v.status.setTag(sms);
    v.selector.setTag(position);

    boolean smsParsed = sms.parsed != null
            && sms.checkFlag(SMS.FLAG_SENDER_OK)
            && sms.checkFlag(SMS.FLAG_FORMAT_OK)
            && sms.checkFlag(SMS.FLAG_ACCOUNT_OK);
    if(smsParsed) {
        v.status_bg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        v.status_bg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (sms.checkFlag(SMS.FLAG_FORMAT_OK)) {
            v.status.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            v.status.setEnabled(true);
        }
        v.status.setText(getSMSStatus(sms));
        v.status.setEventListener(new ContextMenu.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(ContextMenu v, int index) {
                SMS sms = (SMS) v.getTag();
                if (index == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("message/rfc822");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"support@zenmoney.ru", ""});
                    String subj = getSMSStatus(sms) + "["+ ZenMoney.getVersionName()+"]";
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subj);
                    String text = context.getString(R.string.sms_mail);
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String.format(text, sms.sender, sms.text));
                    try {
                        i = Intent.createChooser(i, context.getString(R.string.sms_app_choose));
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.no_apps), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (MainActivity.DEBUG && index == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, SmsTestActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("sms_sender", sms.sender);
                    i.putExtra("sms_body", sms.text);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

        });

    }
    v.selector.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            SMS sms = smsList.get(position);
            Long id = sms._id;
            if (!isChecked) {
                checked.remove(id);
            } else if (!checked.contains(id)) {
                checked.add(id);
            }
            if (checked.size() > 0) {
                SmsScreen.showBottomCAB();
            } else {
                SmsScreen.hideBottomCAB();
            }
        }
    });
    if (view == null) {
        ZenMoney.uncaughtException(new NullPointerException());
    }
    return view;
}
```

Here is error log:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1482)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1786)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:705)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:762)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1639)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1310)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1528)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1290)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1166)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1083)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1290)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1166)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1083)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:943)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1290)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1279)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1085)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onLayout(CustomViewAbove.java:426)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:943)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7224)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1181)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1913)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Question is: why does this error occur and how can I avoid it?

Updated: Problem is solved. I just got confused in adapters and used another one. Sorry :)

Comment: Yes your adapter checks for it and just pops it back. And if you don't catch it there is your NullPointerExecption

Comment: You are doing something wrong in your adapter yet. Please post the relevant portions of code.

Comment: ok, i've published it as edit

Comment: is there a possibility that your `v` is `null`, try telling us the exact point where your exception happens. You probably wanted to use 'findViewById` not `getTag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you check whether the pointer is null and if it is you throw NullPointerException anyway.  You need to do something sensible for the case the pointer is null instead of throwing NullPointerException.  Otherwise you might as well not check.

Comment: No. I updated code, now it reports through Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), e);

And there is no errors reported.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the getView method, it should be implemented this way...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null) { 
         //inflate
    }
    ....

    return view;
}
```

check http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I know aboit it and this is the way that my getView was implemented. In code i pasted only the end of method.